# Failing async task on a multi instance subprocess stops all the other processes jbpm

Tags: jbpm

I have a process definition where a multi instance subprocess has a reusable process with an error boundary event attached. The scope is to process many files. If one fails, I need the others to continue execution. Everything works fine for Sync tasks (defined in the reusable process), but not for the async ones. When a async task fails, all the other processes fail with the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you share some code?

Comment: would it even better if you could share the error logs/

Comment: Not actual any more because the strategy has changed from SINGLETON to PER_PROCESS_INSTANCE and I've got some other issues now. Thanks anyway.